# How to read through an HTML document text and replace string within brackets from API call response

Tags: javascript, c#, forms, asp.net-core

I am writing a document creator using a text editor that has placeholder tags ([[tagname]]). I need to be able to send the HTML text to a reader that will find each placeholder and replace it with the response text from an API call.

I have the reader service accepting the HTML text and I've tried splitting on (" ") to separate each word, running the word through a for loop and calling the .Between service extension method on ("[[", "]]") to find the placeholders. Then I am doing a switch on the placeholders it finds and calling methods within the reader service to make the API calls. The problem is that the end result is an empty string. I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
    public string ReadForm(FormViewModel formModel)
    {
        var form = "";

        var formText = formModel.FormText;
        formText.Split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < formText.Length; i++)
        {
            var formTextIndex = formText[i].ToString();
            var formTagItem = formTextIndex.Between("[[", "]]");
            if (formTagItem.ToString() != null)
            {
                switch (formTagItem)
                {
                    case "placeholder1":
                        formTagItem = GetItems1(formModel.ID);
                        form += $"{formTagItem} ";
                        break;
                    case "placeholder2":
                        formTagItem = GetItems2(formModel.ID);
                        form += $"{formTagItem} ";
                        break;
                    case "placeholder3":
                        formTagItem = GetItems3(formModel.ID);
                        form += $"{formTagItem} ";
                        break;
                    case "placeholder4":
                        formTagItem = GetItems4(formModel.ID);
                        form += $"{formTagItem} ";
                        break;
                    default:
                        form += $"{formTagItem} ";
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                form += $"{formText[i]} ";
            }
        }

        return form;
    }
```

My expected result for the form would be that the placeholders would be replaced with the returned values and then be replaced within the HTML text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Find/Replace may be what you're looking for.

Using statements:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Method:

```
public string ReadForm(FormViewModel formModel)
{
    string formText = formModel.FormText;
    formText = formText.Replace("[[placeholder1]]", GetItems1(formModel.ID));
    formText = formText.Replace("[[placeholder2]]", GetItems2(formModel.ID));
    formText = formText.Replace("[[placeholder3]]", GetItems3(formModel.ID));
    formText = formText.Replace("[[placeholder4]]", GetItems4(formModel.ID));
    formText = Regex.Replace(formText, @"\[\[(.*?)\]\]", "$1");
    return formText;
}
```

The **Regex.Replace** accomplishes what the **default** block does: replaces anything inside a tag with the name inside the tag.